# Extract email adresses from several files with Windows CMD

Tags: email, cmd, extract, findstr

I have around 1000 txt.files containing a lot of data  like email adresses, name, Zip code, services ... On this folder : C:\Users\dupont\Documents\test
I would like to extract all the email adresses and only email adresses on this folder and copy it it another .txt file.

So I created a .bat like that to extract email adresses :

```
findstr @ C:\Users\dupont\Documents\test\ad.txt >C:\Users\dupont\Documents\test\results.txt
pause
```

The problem is that, it extracts all the line
Moreover, I do not know how to ask on the command, to delimit the search of the string with '@' to a space, tab, carriage return
Indeed, the command has to match with @, the word before @ (until space) and the word after @( until the space

Thanks for your help
Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each textfile (`%%f`) process each line (`%%a`) one after the other. Split the line into elements (`%%b`) by spaces (Standard delimters are space and TAB) and if the element contains a `@`, print it:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%%f) do (
    for %%b in (%%a) do (
      echo %%b|find "@"
    )
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks you Stephan it was exactly what I needed :)